# jQuery AJAX on HTTPS - Resource failed to load

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl, https

I have own API at `http(s)://www.api.domain.com` (on HTTPS there is RapidSSL installed).

If I acccess that URL via browser I get

```
{"error":{"code":404,"message":"Invalid API version."}}
```

which is fine.

If I access `https://www.api.domain.com/v1/auth` I get

`{"error":{"code":404,"message":"Missing authorization header."}}`

which is also OK (sign that API works OK on SSL).

I have jQuery AJAX call to that API from other domain. If I make a call without SSL (`http://www.api.domain.com/v1/auth`) everything is working OK (I'm sending authorization headers and all other necessary stuff) and I'm getting responses. If I try to access to the same thing but with SSL (`https://www.api.domain.com/v1/auth`) I get `OPTIONS https://www.api.domain.com/v1/auth Resource failed to load`.

Also, **CORS** is working. On PHP side I have

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, x-domain-accesskey, X-Requested-With');
    exit;
}
```

so it's working, but only without SSL. In chrome I see one **OPTIONS** request and then **GET/POST/whatever** I requested. It's working just fine.

But when I try to move on HTTPS,

> Resource failed to load

On Network tab I have only this (not sure why on the first image is showing **OPTIONS**, but on the details **POST**)

[image]

[image]

[image]

and then just...stops? In jQuery it stops on line

```
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
```

`$.ajax` is normal (don't have `crossDomain: true`, `dataType: jsonp` or something else).

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the page youre sending the https ajax request from render in https and it should work fine for you.

Comment: I am also getting the same problem. But could not understand what you said above. Can you please explain in detail.

Comment: @shashaDenovo if you are loading a page via https, you have to also call the script via https, you should also call the script via https, not http.  There are a few different ways to implement this, google analytics script for example detects the protocol in advance.  Youtube embedded videos do sometihng like `://script_name`

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error in chrome console to the line where it stopped, as well as lots of 404 (admin-ajax.php not found) and some 500 errors when in wordpress admin.

```
g.send(b.hasContent && b.data || null)
```

Reading @Rooster's solution made me think about htaccess for my https SSL cert site which was still the default wordpress file. By adding this above it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

The "code forces a request to http://example.com to load https://example.com. It also forces directly linked resources (images, css, etc.) to use https"

see:- https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747758-Force-your-site-to-load-securely-with-an-htaccess-file.

So in the end your file should look like the below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE] 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Hope that helps, solved some of my errors.